# Can not update Value

Tags: android, android-view

I have a class(constant.class). Which contain all the constant value that needs to be updated. I have a method in main activity. It update constant value(a url) and execute a view class(contain webview). But the value of url can not update in constant.class. so in the view 
the webview looks white. I have to update the value of url in constant.class. here is my constant class:

```
public class Constant {

public static boolean isCapturedOk = false;

public static int imagePickerStatus = -1;

public static byte[] imageData;

public static int result = 0;

public static String printUrl = "";

public static String rotationValue="";

public static String rotationValueForCamera="";

public static boolean isPrintButtonVisible = true;
```

}

Here is my View class:

```
public class PrintView extends LinearLayout {

WebView wev;
public PrintView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.printscreen, this);
    wev = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewPrint);
    wev.loadUrl("http://www.vividworks.com/");

}

public PrintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.printscreen, this);
    wev = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewPrint);
    wev.loadUrl("http://www.vividworks.com/");

}

public PrintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.printscreen, this);
    wev = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewPrint);
    wev.loadUrl("http://www.vividworks.com/");

}



@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i = 0 ; i < getChildCount() ; i++){
        getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the method in main activity:

```
  public void loadPrintActivity(String printUrl){
   Constant.printUrl = printUrl;
   Constant.isPrintButtonVisible  =true;
   pv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
```

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do any changes to class variables, you make Objects of class and use its properties and methods.

Comment: Hi Mohammad where you call loadPrintActivity(String printUrl) and what value passed in it please explain so that we can help you.

Comment: @Nand, i want to pass printUrl to constant.class. And use it to printview.class. That's why i want to put this value into constant.class.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me. PLz plz plz...............

Comment: @shree202 how can i do that?

Comment: @MohammadRajob It should be update first check your value of printUrl which is assign to Constant.printUrl

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your `Constant` class into a [`Java singleton class`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm)

This way you can get the one `instance` of the class, edit its fields using `getters` and `setters`.

This is roughly what the class would look like:

```
private Constant() {
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
}

public static Constant getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new Constant();
    }
    return instance;
}

add getters and setters
```

In each activity you can get the `Constant` like so:

```
Constant c = Constant.getInstance();
```

Then set the URL or whatever as normal

```
e.g. c.setURL("urlhere");
```

Comment: What part do you not understand? And have you clicked on the link (it goes into more detail explaining it )